# Firebase Stripe - listening to a createCheckoutSession function executed by the stripe extension

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I am trying to find a way to listen to a function createCheckoutSession fired by Stripe extension. To be exact, i want to find a way to inform the front-end(React Native) when the function createCheckoutSession execution has finished:

[image]

How to do it in my front-end?

Comment: I don't have any experience with this but wouldn't your frontend already know? Like your frontend is what calls the backend Firebase function to trigger this, so it should be getting back the response and can act on it.

Comment: The thing is that since i am using the firebase stripe extension, all the functions are called by the extension, i didn't have to configure them, so i don't understand how can i handle these functions and events that are sent through the webhook.